# Is the Javascript version for UDFs specified?

Tags: google-bigquery

Apologies if I've overlooked it here or in the bigquery docs, but is there any way to find the version of Javascript in which UDFs will execute?

Comment: I don't think we state which version we use, but BigQuery uses a sandboxed v8 environment. Are you looking for specific functionality from a recent version of v8?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard -- Thanks for the reply, and my apologies for not responding until nearly a year later. I must not have had notifications set up properly, and only just now logged back in here for the first time.

In case it is helpful still to know, the reason was that I wanted to understand whether I would be guaranteed the presence of basic iterators and other Javascript types, such as `Array.forEach`, etc.